# Why does my jquery slideshow work in all browsers except IE 11?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a simple jquery slideshow that I downloaded from this site linked below. It has 3 slides that show some basketball players. The slideshow displays correctly in Chrome and Edge, but in IE 11 (11.76 to be exact) I get an error message "Object doesn't support property or method 'flexslider'." Is there any way to get this slideshow to work in IE 11? All I want is for the user to be taken directly to the "Bulls" slide of the slideshow when they click on the "Bulls anchor link test" link at the bottom of the page.

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/asnavfor-rtl.html

I've tested this on other browsers and when I click on the team anchor links at the bottom of the page, it takes me to the appropriate team's slide when the page loads. But in IE 11, I see all 3 slides jammed into the first slide of the 3-slide slideshow, and the other 2 slides remain empty.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-f6DVw/U4x2+HjgEqw5BZf67Kq/5vudRZuRkljnbF344=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://louisville.edu/artsandsciences/styles/experimental/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bergantine/3868451/raw/a67f7e7989068013bfd0341cd523b843105c6d8d/gistfile1.js"></script> <!--referred to as modernizr.js in the flexslider package-->


<script type="text/javascript">


    $(window).load(function() {

      $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 230,
        itemMargin: 5,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
      });

      $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        sync: "#carousel"
      });   

        /*when this page loads, one of the teams will be pre-selected based on the anchor link in the URL*/
        if(window.location.hash == "#Celtics") {TeamTransition('2', "https://d1si3tbndbzwz9.cloudfront.net/basketball/team/1/logo.png");}
        else if(window.location.hash == "#Bulls") {TeamTransition('3', "http://www.logospng.com/images/80/chicago-watercolor-skyline-silhouette-vector-download-80974.png");}
        else {TeamTransition('1', "https://d1si3tbndbzwz9.cloudfront.net/basketball/team/18/logo.png");}

    });


    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#carousel span").click(function(){
            $("#carousel span").css("background-color","#e0e0e0");
            $("#carousel span").css("color","#0D3347");
            $(this).css("background","#3d758c");
            $(this).css("color","white");   
            var TeamButtonText = $(this).text();    
            var TeamLogoLink = "https://d1si3tbndbzwz9.cloudfront.net/basketball/team/18/logo.png";
            if(TeamButtonText == "Celtics"){TeamLogoLink = "https://d1si3tbndbzwz9.cloudfront.net/basketball/team/1/logo.png"}
            else if(TeamButtonText == "Bulls"){TeamLogoLink = "http://www.logospng.com/images/80/chicago-watercolor-skyline-silhouette-vector-download-80974.png"}
            else{TeamButtonText == "https://d1si3tbndbzwz9.cloudfront.net/basketball/team/18/logo.png"}
            $("#banner_studio_logo_pic").animate({height:0},300,function() {
                $('#banner_studio_logo_pic').attr("src", TeamLogoLink);
                $("#banner_studio_logo_pic").animate({height:75},300);
             });
        });     
    });

    function TeamTransition(slideNumber, studioIconLink) {
        $('#carousel .flex-viewport .slides li:nth-child(' + slideNumber + ') a span').click();
    }


</script>

<style>

    #topBanner{background: #368dd4; height: 120px;}

    #topBanner span{
        display: inline-block; 
        margin-left: 16px; 
        color: white; 
        margin-top: 35px; 
        font-size: 37px !important;
    }

    #topBanner #banner_studio_logo_pic{
        margin-left: 50px;
        height: 75px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-bottom: 14px;
    }

    #ContentContainer{height: 500px; background-color: #c5c5c5;}
    .flexslider{border: none !important;}
    #carousel{background-color: transparent;}
    #carousel li{text-align: center;}

    #carousel span{
        color: #0D3347; 
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 37px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
        background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }

    #carousel .slides{margin-top: 16px;}    
    #slider{background: none; width: 737px !important;}
    #slider .flex-nav-prev a, #slider .flex-nav-next a{display: none;}   /*hide the left and right arrows of the slide show body*/
    .Team_Container{width: 737px; text-align: center;}
    .grid_cell{display: inline; margin-right: 33px;}

</style>


<div id="topBanner">
    <span>Teams</span>
    <img id="banner_studio_logo_pic" src="https://d1si3tbndbzwz9.cloudfront.net/basketball/team/18/logo.png">
</div>

<div id="ContentContainer">


    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li><a href="#"><span style="background: rgba(22, 93, 122, 0.5); color: white;">Lakers</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Celtics</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Bulls</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>  

    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">

        <li id="slide1">
            <div class="Team_Container">    
                <div class="grid_cell"><span>Magic Johnson</span></div>         
                <div class="grid_cell"><span>James Worthy</span></div>          
            </div>          
        </li>  

        <li id="slide2">
            <div class="Team_Container">    
                <div class="grid_cell"><span>Larry Bird</span></div>
                <div class="grid_cell"><span>Kevin McHale</span></div>
            </div>          
        </li>

        <li id="slide3">
            <div class="Team_Container">
                <div class="grid_cell"><span>Michael Jordan</span></div>
                <div class="grid_cell"><span>Scottie Pippen</span></div>    
            </div>  
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<p><a href="#Lakers" onclick="location.hash='Lakers'; location.reload();">Lakers anchor link test</a></p>
<p><a href="#Celtics" onclick="location.hash='Celtics'; location.reload();">Celtics anchor link test</a></p>
<p><a href="#Bulls" onclick="location.hash='Bulls'; location.reload();">Bulls anchor link test</a></p>
```

I get the message "Object doesn't support property or method 'flexslider'" when I look at the IE console.

Comment: Try moving your flexslider calls inside the $(document).ready, not $(window).load

Comment: @circusdei I tried that and it didn't work unfortunately :(